# Powershell Script to get the number of lines updated in last one hour

Tags: powershell, filereader, powershell-4.0

I have to count the number of lines of an updating file in last one hour.
The updating file is a log file which keeps updating and I have to keep counting the number of lines updated every hour.
Since, I have to count the number of lines in one hour time span, using sleep or wait don't seems feasible to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the lines contain some kind of timestamp ?

Comment: As D.J. says, if there is a timestamp on the rows it should be fairly easy to extract the data and the parse based on the time stamp.

If there isn't, you could copy the file off and compare it to a 1 hour older file. Count the lines in each file and do some maths. Then update the 1 hour old file with the new one, Repeat in 1 hour.

Comment: If the log isn't rotated you could also skip the previous number of lines and count the remainder.